# How to change CollapsingToolbarLayout typeface and size?

Tags: android, fonts, toolbar, font-size, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I want to change `CollapsingToolbarLayout` font size and its typeface. How I can achieve that?

[image]

Comment: tried setCollapsedTitleTextAppearance(); and setCollapsedTitleTextColor(); function ?

Comment: @abhishek, it isn't what I looking for. I can't change typeface via xml.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looks like I have solution:

```
private void makeCollapsingToolbarLayoutLooksGood(CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbarLayout) {
    try {
        final Field field = collapsingToolbarLayout.getClass().getDeclaredField("mCollapsingTextHelper");
        field.setAccessible(true);

        final Object object = field.get(collapsingToolbarLayout);
        final Field tpf = object.getClass().getDeclaredField("mTextPaint");
        tpf.setAccessible(true);

        ((TextPaint) tpf.get(object)).setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Roboto-Bold.ttf"));
        ((TextPaint) tpf.get(object)).setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.ice));
    } catch (Exception ignored) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 145):

## Update

Before we dive into the code let's first decide the `textSize` for our `CollapsingToolbarLayout`. Google published a website called `material.io`, this website also explains the best way on how to deal with [Typography](https://material.io/design/typography/the-type-system.html#applying-the-type-scale).

The article mentioned about "Heading" category which also explains the recommended font size to use in `sp`.

[image]

Although the article never mentioned the recommended `CollapsingToolbarLayout's` **expanded** size but the library `com.android.support:design` provides a `TextAppearance` for our case. With some digging with the source it turns out that that the size is `34sp` (not mentioned in the article).

So how about the collapsed size? Luckily the article mentioned something and it is `20sp`.

[image]

And the best `TextAppearance` so far that fits in **collpased** mode is  `TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title` while our **expanded** mode `TextAppearance` is `TextAppearance.Design.CollapsingToolbar.Expanded`.

If you observe all our examples above all of them uses the *REGULAR* version of the font which is safe to say that `Roboto regular` will do the task unless you have specific requirements.

It might be too much work downloading the fonts itself why not use a library that has all the needed Roboto fonts? So I introduce a calligraphy library for Roboto e.g. [Typer](https://github.com/rhexgomez/typer).

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.rhexgomez.typer:typer-roboto:2.0.0'
}
```

```
<android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Design.CollapsingToolbar.Expanded"
            app:collapsedTitleTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">
```

### Java

```
// Java example
CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbar = findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar);
collapsingToolbar.setCollapsedTitleTypeface(TyperRoboto.ROBOTO_REGULAR());
collapsingToolbar.setExpandedTitleTypeface(TyperRoboto.ROBOTO_REGULAR());
```

### Kotlin

```
// Kotlin example
collapsing_toolbar.apply {
    setCollapsedTitleTypeface(TyperRoboto.ROBOTO_REGULAR)
    setExpandedTitleTypeface(TyperRoboto.ROBOTO_REGULAR)
}
```

---

*<sub>This is a 2019 update because the Typer library is updated! I am also the author of the library.</sub>*

Comment: is there anyway to set margin to collapse title ,

Comment: @Mr.G use                     app:titleMargin=""
 on your Toolbar.

Answer (score 84):

You can use the new public methods, on `CollapsingToolbarLayout` to set the typeface for the collapsed and expanded title, like so:

```
final Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/FrutigerLTStd-Light.otf");
collapsingToolbar.setCollapsedTitleTypeface(tf);
collapsingToolbar.setExpandedTitleTypeface(tf);
```

This seems to have been added in the design support library 23.1.0, and is a very welcome addition.

Comment: How do you change the Title? I want to set the Title to a different text programmatically.

Comment: You can probably use the `setTitle(String)` method on the `CollapsingToolbarLayout` instance.

Answer (score 75):

You can do something like this:

```
mCollapsingToolbarLayout.setTitle(getTitle());
mCollapsingToolbarLayout.setExpandedTitleTextAppearance(R.style.ExpandedAppBar);
mCollapsingToolbarLayout.setCollapsedTitleTextAppearance(R.style.CollapsedAppBar);
```

Corresponding textview style could be:

```
<style name="ExpandedAppBar" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
    <item name="android:textSize">28sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#000</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>

<style name="CollapsedAppBar" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
    <item name="android:textSize">24sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
</style>
```

also see [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=175808#c7) for reference.

Comment: This did the work for me of changing the title text color, since I find that ``Toolbar.setTitleTextColor()`` or ``app:titleTextColor`` of ``Toolbar`` doesnt change the color of title of toolbar when enclosed in ``CollapsingToolbarLayout``

Comment: @patrickjason91 u must use `CollapsingToolbarLayout toolbar_layout =findViewById(R.id.toolbar_layout);
        toolbar_layout.setExpandedTitleColor(Color.BLACK);`

Answer (score 15):

To add to all the answers here,
It did not work for me in xml no matter where I tried to apply, in AppTheme, referencing in  styles. I am currently using support library 27.1.1

It worked only programatically.

```
Typeface typeface = ResourcesCompat.getFont(this, R.font.my_custom_font);
collapsingToolbarLayout.setCollapsedTitleTypeface(typeface);
collapsingToolbarLayout.setExpandedTitleTypeface(typeface);
```

Comment: Make sure to **set the Collapsing toolbar title first**. Set **setCollapsedTitleTypeFace** after setting the title worked for me.

Comment: yes it worked for me and should work for who uses 'font' folder.

Answer (score 14):

```
    mCollapsingToolbar.setTitle(getTitle());
    mCollapsingToolbar.setExpandedTitleTextAppearance(R.style.ExpandedAppBar);
    mCollapsingToolbar.setCollapsedTitleTextAppearance(R.style.CollapsedAppBar);

<style name="ExpandedAppBar" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
    <item name="android:textSize">28sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#000</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>

<style name="CollapsedAppBar" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
    <item name="android:textSize">24sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
</style>

<style name="ExpandedAppBarPlus1" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
    <item name="android:textSize">28.5sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#000</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>

<style name="CollapsedAppBarPlus1" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
    <item name="android:textSize">24.5sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
</style>
```

Reference here [CollapsingToolbarLayout setTitle not work correctly](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=175808#makechanges)

Answer (score 13):

Code is here

```
 <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/Toolbar.TitleText"
            app:collapsedTitleTextAppearance="@style/Toolbar.TitleText"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="@dimen/expanded_toolbar_title_margin_start"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">
```

Add these code lines in CollapsingToolbarLayout layout

```
 app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/Toolbar.TitleText"
 app:collapsedTitleTextAppearance="@style/Toolbar.TitleText"
```

And the code which is given below, in style.xml

```
<style name="Toolbar.TitleText" parent="TextAppearance.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Title">
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
</style>
```

Comment: is there anyway to set margin to collapse title ?

Answer (score 5):

Change the font size or parent.

```
<style name="expandedappbar" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"> //Change Medium to Small
    <item name="android:textSize">28sp</item>  <!--Or Change the font size -->
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>

<style name="collapsedappbar" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
    <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

### Android 8.0 (API level 26) have introduces a new feature, Fonts in XML

Now you can define fonts as resource https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml.html

- Put your fonts in in `res-> font->` folder
- Define font.xml

> ```
>    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
>       <font-family xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
>         <font
>             android:fontStyle="normal"
>             android:fontWeight="400"
>             android:font="@font/lobster_regular" />
>         <font
>             android:fontStyle="italic"
>             android:fontWeight="400"
>             android:font="@font/lobster_italic" />
>     </font-family>
> ```

next set

```
    val typeface = ResourcesCompat.getFont(this, R.font.lobster_regular)
    htab_collapse_toolbar.setCollapsedTitleTypeface(typeface)
    htab_collapse_toolbar.setExpandedTitleTypeface(typeface)
```