# CollapsingToolbarLayout's setCollapsedTitleTextColor and setExpandedTitleColor don't do anything

Tags: android, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I'm trying to set the expanded and collapsed CollapsingToolbarLayout's title text color to be different, but no matter what I do, it is always white.

Here is the code in question:

```
mCollapsingToolbar.setCollapsedTitleTextColor(getResources.getColor(R.color.foo));
mCollapsingToolbar.setExpandedTitleColor(getResources.getColor(R.color.bar));
```

In my layout XML file, I'm not specifying any color styles on either the AppBarLayout, the CollapsingToolbarLayout, or the Toolbar itself.

Is there some sort of interference with my Activity's theme settings?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to try below code:

```
private void changeCollapsedTitleTextColor(CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbarLayout) {
try {
    final Field field = collapsingToolbarLayout.getClass().getDeclaredField("mCollapsingTextHelper");
    field.setAccessible(true);

    final Object object = field.get(collapsingToolbarLayout);
    final Field tpf = object.getClass().getDeclaredField("mTextPaint");
    tpf.setAccessible(true);

    ((TextPaint) tpf.get(object)).setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.your_color));
} catch (Exception ignored) {
}
}
```

I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31738831/how-to-change-collapsingtoolbarlayout-typeface-and-size).
I hope it may help you.