# How to change the font of toolbar title in CollapsingToolbarLayout?

Tags: android, fonts, toolbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I've been trying numerous trial and errors on changing its styles but I still can't get the toolbar title's font change (I'm also using Calligraphy library) and not sure whether the toolbar title's property is on toolbar or on CollapsingToolbarLayout.
Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

[image]

Comment: `numerous trial and errors` Please enumerate so we don't repeat what you did unnecessarily.

Comment: Hope it is a duplicate questions... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31738831/how-to-change-collapsingtoolbarlayout-typeface-and-size

Comment: Referring this to this question's answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36560292/how-to-increase-font-size-of-title-in-collapsingtoolbarlayout