# How to increase font size of title in CollapsingToolbarLayout?

Tags: android, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I tried to add this on my `Collapsing Toolbar Layout`.

`app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"`

app_bar_home.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/CoordinatorLayout"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/AppBarLayout"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleGravity="center|center_horizontal"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
    app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title">

        <ImageView
            app:backgroundTint="@color/text"
            android:id="@+id/canteen_logo"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.7"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/canteen_logo1"
            />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/toolbar_popup_style"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

And here's my Styles.xml:

```
<style name="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title">
    <item name="android:textSize">32sp</item>
</style>
```

This is what I have in my Home.java and tried to remove them but I still couldn't get it fixed.

```
CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbar = (CollapsingToolbarLayout)
            findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar);
    final Typeface sp = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(), "fonts/FuturaPTMedium.otf");
    final Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(), "fonts/FuturaPTBook.otf");
    collapsingToolbar.setCollapsedTitleTypeface(sp);
    collapsingToolbar.setExpandedTitleTypeface(tf);
    setTitle("CANTEEN");
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change CollapsingToolbarLayout typeface and size?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31738831/how-to-change-collapsingtoolbarlayout-typeface-and-size)

Comment: Hey Jovie, this works fine for me. Perhaps you can post more of the layout code, so we can see if anything else is interfering? Also, how is the title being set? The relevant java code might help too.

Comment: @PaulBurke the title has been automatically set when the activity has been created but I made it uppercase by adding setTitle("CANTEEN"); in onCreate on my activity.

Comment: If  you want to change font size of collapsed text you can use app:collapsedTitleTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title" in your CollapsingToolBarLayout tag

Answer (score 4):

Fixed it by adding this to the activity onCreate:

```
    CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbar = (CollapsingToolbarLayout)
    findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar);
    collapsingToolbar.setCollapsedTitleTextAppearance(R.style.CollapsedAppBar);
    collapsingToolbar.setExpandedTitleTextAppearance(R.style.ExpandedAppBar);
```

and adding this to styles.xml:

```
    <style name="CollapsedAppBar" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textSize">32sp</item>
</style>

<style name="ExpandedAppBar" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textSize">76sp</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Also you can add the following into your app_bar_home.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:collapsedTitleTextAppearance="@style/collapsed_app_bar"
        app:contentScrim="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title.Inverse"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">
```

Then Notice **collapsedTitleTextAppearace** and **expandedTitleTextAppearance** attributes. In my case I add the following into the style.xml under the values resource file:

```
<style name="collapsed_app_bar" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textSize">40sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#f0f</item>
</style>
```

Hope this helps!!