# Android x collapsing toolbar font family cannot be change

Tags: android, androidx

I am trying to change collapsible toolbar font. my code is below

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbarlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/id_collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:contentScrim="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|snap|enterAlways"
        app:title="App Title">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/img" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:theme="@style/TextViewCustomFont"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

<style name="TextViewCustomFont">
    <item name="android:fontFamily">fonts/Montserrat-SemiBold.ttf</item>
</style>
```

also I'm using calligraphy3, 
So, I tried fontPath instead of android:fontFamily
Then, i moved and checked android:theme="@style/TextViewCustomFont" to CollapsingToolbarLayout from Toolbar and with all those combination.

I didn't able to change font style.

Remember this is androidx not old one. there are lot of old question's are there in stackoverflow but none of them working as it is old.

Comment: Not sure, but I think hyphen "-" in the font file name "Montserrat-SemiBold" is causing the problem. Have you tried removing or replacing with underscore "_"?

Comment: @SafalFrom2050 Yes i tried and the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have one id like this in `CollapsingToolbarLayout` layout

```
 <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/id_collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:contentScrim="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|snap|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:title="App Title">
```

Then, inside `onCreate` method add the below line

```
CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbar = findViewById(R.id.id_collapsing_toolbar);
final Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Montserrat-SemiBold.ttf");
collapsingToolbar.setCollapsedTitleTypeface(tf);
collapsingToolbar.setExpandedTitleTypeface(tf);
```

Answer (score 4):

In `CollapsingToolbar` you need to call `expandedTitleTextAppearance`, `collapsedTitleTextAppearance`

**XML**

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
    app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/TextViewCustomFont"
    app:collapsedTitleTextAppearance="@style/TextViewCustomFont"/>
```

**Java**

```
// Java example
CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbar = findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar);
collapsingToolbar.setCollapsedTitleTypeface(TyperRoboto.ROBOTO_REGULAR());
collapsingToolbar.setExpandedTitleTypeface(TyperRoboto.ROBOTO_REGULAR());
```

**Kotlin**

```
// Kotlin example
collapsing_toolbar.apply {
    setCollapsedTitleTypeface(TyperRoboto.ROBOTO_REGULAR)
    setExpandedTitleTypeface(TyperRoboto.ROBOTO_REGULAR)
}
```

You can get a much more detailed answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32679347/5362029)

Comment: You are the person 3 who answered the same. i don't why you people are getting it done where i'm not getting. anyhow others deleted their answers. can you confirm it is working properly. can you kindly make a simple project on that and share it on drive or somewhere or the best  make video on Youtube. Seriously I'm not getting the answer thank you

Comment: How are you setting your title? 
I'm not deleting my answer because I'm almost sure I know the answer, and If not I'll learn something new

Comment: don't remove answer because https://stackoverflow.com/a/33174619/12255535 gives the answer for this question which is below the answer what you referred. i suggest you to add this line of code in your answer. And final note, by using calligraphy3 we can't achieve this.